# Avoiding Function Calls of an Entire Module - How Bad is this Hack?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a module that generates images. Sometimes I want to skip it so I have devised the following hack:

```
import visualization


def main(skip_figs: ("Skip making figures", 'flag', 's')):

    if skip_figs:
        def fake(*args, **kwargs):
            pass
        for k, v in vis.__dict__.items():
            if callable(v):
                vis.__dict__[k] = fake

    ## This line would be "skipped"
    visualization.plot_something(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        import plac; plac.call(main)
    except:
        import pdb, sys, traceback
        _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
        traceback.print_exc()
        pdb.post_mortem(tb)
```

Is it a bad idea? It seems to work. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this? Of course, I can write an`if else` clause for each function call from `visualizations` but I got lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `visualization` a `unittest.mock.Mock` instance instead:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock
import visualization

...

if skip_figs:
    visualization = Mock()
visualization.plot_something(x, y)
```